# Excel, search data in different Sheet2 and put it back on Sheet1 based on their column

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is Sheet1

[image]

This is Sheet2

[image]

I would like to search the Fruit in Sheet2, identify their group, and put it back in Sheet1, under column B (Group)

Desired output

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Btw, if you want to replicate this (copy paste), [here](https://pastebin.com/eJDvfEWL) is the similar data

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a simpler way to do this, but I can't remember what it is!

Anyway, this will work:

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7),0)*{1,2,3}),{1,2,3},{"A","B","C"}),"-")
```

[image]

First, we use FIND to create an array that gives us either a 1 if the fruit is found, or a zero if it isn't. This array is the same size as the data on sheet 2 with a 1 where the word Grape was found. By multiplying this array by {1,2,3}, it instead has a 2 where the word grape was found (this is useful so we can tell it was the second column). By summing that array, the result will be 2. We then pass the value 2 into the XLOOKUP, returning the value in the 2nd position from the return array, which is B.

Of course, this will not work if the word Grape is found in more than one cell in Sheet2.

EDIT:

I realised that this way, while longer, is probably better:

```
=XLOOKUP(SUM(($A10=Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7)*COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1)),COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1),CHAR(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1),65,1)),"-")
```

In this instance, the size of the lookup and return arrays is determined by the number of group columns on sheet 2, which means you have no hand-typing of 1,2,3 or "A","B","C".